# Migration of jHipster into TestNG

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, testng, jhipster

I have been trying into moving from JUnit tests into TestNG framwerok for my jHipster application. This task was pretty simple:

1. Add TestNG as a dependency in pom.xml
2. Convert tests into TestNG using Eclipse IDE
3. Add AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests and AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests where it was necessary.

With that steps I was able to successfully run most of my tests, however one class still causes failures.

[image]

After more investigation I have found out that the problem is with mocking of SecurityContext, in class SecurityUtils, **SecurityContext** is returning null Authentication and that makes the test failing.

```
public static String getCurrentUserLogin() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    String userName = null;
    if (authentication != null) {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
            UserDetails springSecurityUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            userName = springSecurityUser.getUsername();
        } else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof String) {
            userName = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
    }
    return userName;
}
```

Does anyone encounter that problem before? Have anyone sucessfully migratet jHipster into TestNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with SecurityContextHolder mocking. I have found solution here:
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/05/mocking-spring-security-context-unit-testing.html

Also important note: TestNG will not return SecurityContextHolder after tests execution so you have to reset its value for following tests:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockedAuthentication = mock(Authentication.class);
    mockedSecurityContext = mock(SecurityContext.class);
    originalSecurityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(mockedSecurityContext);
}

@AfterMethod
public void teardown() {
    Mockito.reset(mockedAuthentication);
    Mockito.reset(mockedSecurityContext);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(originalSecurityContext);
}
```